# Creating an n-dimensional data frame in R

Tags: r

I have need for a data structure of at least three dimensions where the class of one of the dimensions can change.  In 2 dimensions this would be a data frame.  In 3 dimensions I can create an object which is a list of data frames, but will then have to implement enough of the generic functions to make the data structure usable. I will have some functions which are unaware of the 3rd dimension, aggregating the 3rd dimension down so only 2 remain.  In other cases, I will have functions specifically designed to analyze the additional dimensions.

All-in-all, this seems like a hell of a lot of work.  As it seems like a rather generic problem, are there any R packages or data structures which have already solved it?  If my data was all of a single class, I could just use an array, but unfortunately, that's not the case.

Comment: You may be looking for an `array`, though I am not sure if you can store different types in it.

Comment: You need a list. And it's quite possible to make matrices or arrays with lists as elements. Need specifics to support programming efforts. Seems excessively vague at the moment.

Comment: Data frames aren't really 2d like arrays are. You can store data of any dimension in a column, in full or sparse form. You should learn the basics about R's vectors, arrays and data frames and reformulate the question with specifics.